# How to achieve single validation for multiple object property change

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I am using `PropertyGrid.SelectedObjects` (Winform control) property to show properties of multiple objects. I have custom descriptor for each property of each object which does a basic validation and executes business logic.

I would like execute only once the business logic only when all the validations are done. How to we do it?

**Edit**

PropertyGrid control when a value is set automatically uses MergedPropertyDescriptor which calls my custom descriptor's SetValue function in a loop which results in multiple business logic call. Which I want to avoid this without the use of any static variable

**Edit2**
This question is also posted in [Microsoft Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9abc0de0-995b-4b9c-970d-fd64ac117cca/how-to-achieve-single-validationbusiness-logic-execution-for-multiple-object-property-change?forum=winforms)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest:

```
myForm.submit = function() {
  if (checkValidation()) {
    // business logic;
    if (OK) return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

I, personally, would prefer to simply use the submit method as a wrapper (the inner if-statement [when true] would call another [business logic] function which returns true or false).

Comment: the submit method (seen above) can, of course, be changed to a click event for a button element or whatever event handler you want for yoru "SelectedObjectes". I always err on a last 'return false' statement. Not only does it make your code cleaner, but if something you've missed in validation returns poorly, you will always return false. Only functions returning 'true' will pass validation and business logic in the above example.

Comment: I do not know how this will fit in my case. I have updated my question to give more information.